# I am trying to understand why debug is not working for a Web app in Visual Studio Professional 13

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-4.5

First, I have IIS Express and IIS8 installed. I have followed a plethora of notes found on the internet regarding this issue. I have uninstalled and installed asp.net 4.5. I registered asp.net with the following command: `dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-ASPNET45` (it registered successfully), among many other things. The error that I consistently get now is the following:

```
Unable to start debugging on the web server. IIS does not list a website that matches
the launched URL.
```

UPDATE: I right-clicked and selected to run VS as administrator, now I get this error:

```
 Request filtering is configured for the Web server and the file extension  for this request is explicitly denied.
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. I have been wrestling with this issue for several hours now .... Code is below:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="BOT.master.cs" Inherits="BOTWebApplication1.BOT" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Truth</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function mainmenu() {
        $(" #nav ul ").css({ display: "none" }); // Opera Fix

        $(" #nav li").hover(function () {
            $(this).find('ul:first').css({ visibility: "visible", display: "none" }).show(400);
        }
        , function () {
            $(this).find('ul:first').css({ visibility: "hidden" });
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        mainmenu();
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Styles/BOTStyleSheet.css" />

</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="banner">

            <pre><br />Believers              <br FREE                             <br />Church   </pre>

        </div>

        <div id="navigation">
            <ul id="nav">
                <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ABOUT BELIEVERS</a>
                   <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Pastor</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Directory</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Belief</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">MINISTRIES</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CALENDAR</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>

            </ul>

        </div>

        <div id="content_area">

        </div>

        <div id="sidebar">

        </div>

        <div id="footer">
            <p>All rights reserved.</p>
        </div>


    </div>

</form>
```

Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
 -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
        <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Execute, Script" />
    </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Are you running VS as administrator?

Comment: @RodgerTheGreat Yes ....

Comment: @RodgerTheGreat I right-clicked on VS an selected "run as Administrator", and this time when I attempted to debug, I got the following error: Request filtering is configured for the Web server and the file extension for this request is explicitly denied.

Comment: can you post your web.config

Comment: @RodgerTheGreat Posted...